# columns and horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, column-count, css-multicolumn-layout

I want to add items into a list dinamically and when I do this, the order is so weird, when I add the first item, this stick to the left, when I add the second one, this go to center, and the third item go to rigth, all good so far, but, when I add the fourth element, I got 2 columns instead of 3 columns.

This is what I want

```
|  1  | |  2  | |  3  |
|  4  |
```

And this is what I get

```
|  1  | |  2  |
|  3  | |  4  |
```

I really need to use the column-count (because I need to horizontally scroll the list when this fill 9 elements, so, the element number 10 will be out of the screen and the horizontal scroll will appear).

Any idea of how achieve this?

Comment: Post your existing code. And these aren't columns, they're rows... columns would put 2 below 1, not beside it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using inline-block Elements for your List.
Use block Elements instead and float your Listitems or use Flexbox.

```
<span>1<\span>
<span>2<\span>
...

span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
}
```

But Michael is right, for better Answers, always post your Code or at least an Example of it.